# release management 2013 delete stage / release

Tags: ms-release-management

I have an agent based release that for temporary test purposes I added a stage to at the front of the path (a component needed some of the output), I ran two test releases and now that I've copied my test steps into the correct template I'd like to delete the stage.

The problem is that I'm getting this as an error message:

To remove this stage, it must be removed from the following releases:
Test Release
Test Release 2

Both of the releases are currently in an abandoned state.

I've deleted all of the content from the stage in the template and moved the stage to the end of the path so practically it's not problem BUT from a keeping the pipeline/templates clean I would like to remove the stage from the path.

Any ideas as to how to perform the delete of either the stage (or releases which I suspect would let me delete the stage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to delete those releases entirely. Microsoft provided some SQL scripts that will allow you to safely clean those up:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2015/11/21/release-management-utilities.aspx

Comment: You are a star, I'll give this a go tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Note this is for RM 2015 not 2013 and Aseem has said will back port the script but I've lots of preparation work to do in the office before I can run this sort of thing on live.